# stdcall required on import function?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm curious about this:

When I import a function from a dynamic link library that exports using **stdcall** calling convention, is it mandatory to add **stdcall** before **external** in Delphi starting from version 7?

i.e.

```
LIBNAME int __stdcall Foo(void);
```

as

```
function Foo: Integer; stdcall; external 'libname.dll';
```

or I can get away with just

```
function Foo: Integer; external 'libname.dll';
```

IIRC by default it will use **stdcall** but I'm not 100% sure on this, your opinion is required.

**EDIT**:

The question is related to 32bit library, Arnaud Bouchez has made a good point that for 64bit, the calling convention is not taken into consideration since there's only one.

Comment: You can "get away with" omitting the calling convention on that function because when there is a simple return type and no parameters, stdcall and register behave identically.

Comment: @RobKennedy damn examples! you right, actually all but one of the functions I import have 1 or more parameters, thank you for the heads-up Rob! (:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you omit `stdcall` then the default calling convention `register` will be used. So you must include that `stdcall`.

The fact that you are using `external` does not change anything. The default calling convention is `register`, even for external imports.

Of course, this only matters when compiling for 32 bit. On x64 Windows there is a single calling convention specified in the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). On x64 Windows, all calling conventions specified in code are ignored and all function calls are made with the Windows x64 calling convention.

Comment: +1 and accepted thank you David, wasn't sure, is this true for all delphi versions?

Comment: @David Not mandatory for Delphi XE2 when building 64 bit applications: there is only one calling convention in this case. Adding stdcall does not change anything.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez that's right! for 64 bit, calling convention is neglected, but in my case it's a 32 bit dll that I'm using, I'll update the question.

Comment: @Arnaud That's right. In practice you leave the stdcall there because it's normal for code to be written so that it can be compiled for both 32 and 64 bit. Could be a while before we drop 32 bit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I always heard the default calling convention referred to as 'fastcall' (and it still is in C++ Builder's Options dialog and auto generated header files.)  The [Delphi documentation definitely uses 'register'](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Calling_Conventions) though. Did the preferred name change at some point in the past, or am I just confused?

Comment: @DavidM It's always been known as register in Delphi. It also gets referred to as Borland fastcall since it is similar and yet subtly different from the MS fastcall.